# Apps script: Calendar App: Check if a user is an optional invite to an event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am writing an apps script solution to run once a day to read all the events from a user's calendar and if the user is an optional attendee for any particular event, the script should automatically color code the event.

While working with the calendar app, I noticed that only the guest list and their status (whether they have accepted the invite or not) is visible via apps script and not the ***"optional"*** or ***"mandatory"*** attendance. Any idea how can this be done?

```
var myCal = CalendarApp.getEventsForDay(new Date("13-Jan-2021")); **//Get calendar events for 13-Jan-21**
for (var i=0;i<myCal.length;i++) **// Loop through each event**
{
    Logger.log("Calendar Invite Name:"+myCal[i].getTitle()); **// Get the title for the event**
    var guests= myCal[i].getGuestList(); **// Get the guest list**
    Logger.log("My Status:"+myStatus[2].getStatus()); **//I can only get the guest status here using the getGuestList method and not their importance.**
}
```

I have checked the Calendar App documentation that Google has and only the following are possible using the getGuestList() method.

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

You can not get the `optional` property of an `attendee` using the [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar), however you can get it using the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview).

### How to do it:

- Add the `Google Calendar API` service in your project. Open the project, at left click `Editor > Services > Add Service` (click on the `+`) and select `Google Calendar API`.
- Use the method [get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) of the resource [Event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) to get the actual `Event`. You need the `calendarId` that can be `'primary'` if you are using your primary calendar and the `eventId` that you can get it in multiple ways. The following proposals assume that there is only one event on that day.

  - Using the `Calendar Service` and `getId`:

  ```js
  var ev = CalendarApp.getEventsForDay(new Date("14-Jan-2021"))[0]
  var event_id = ev.getId().split('@')[0]
  ```

  - Using the `Calendar API` and the method [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

  ```
  var date_start = new Date("14-Jan-2021").toISOString()
  var date_end = new Date("15-Jan-2021").toISOString()
  var calendar_id = 'primary'
  var optional = {
    timeMin : date_start,
    timeMax : date_end
  }
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendar_id,optional)
  var event_id = events.items[0].id
  ```
- Once you have obtained the desired `event resource`, you can get the `attendees` and they have a property called `optional` that is defined only if the value is `True`.

  ```
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendar_id,event_id)
  var att = event.attendees
  for (var i=0; i<att.length; i++){
    var a = att[i]
    var email = a.email
    var op = a.optional
    if (op == null){
      op = false
    }
    console.log('Attendant ' + email + ' has a optional invitation: ' + op)
  }
  ```

### Result

```
Attendant ignacio@egs-sbt098.eu has a optional invitation: false
Attendant testi@egs-sbt098.eu has a optional invitation: false
Attendant pruebu@egs-sbt098.eu has a optional invitation: true
```

### Reference

- [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar)
- [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview)
- [Events.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)
- [Evebts.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)
- [Event: resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)